# Making the "ruler" go along a perfectly straight line?

Tags: 3d-view

I am trying to figure out how I can use the Ruler in Blender as a straight line. What I mean, is that every time I use the ruler, I can never make it a perfectly straight line. The picture below shows:

[image: ruler in blender not straight]

Is there any way to make the ruler go along a straight line, just as how the knife tool is able to go along a straight line, when I press "C". The picture below shows the demonstration.

[image: knife tool angle snapping]

Comment: Oh, yeah... the infamous ruler. I've never been able to get that thing to work the way I want it to, so I find it easier to just create temporary geometry to measure or snap to and then delete it when done. Still, I hope someone can provide an answer on this.

Comment: I understand. Maybe there is no such feature in the ruler application in Blender. Hopefully the developers can add, such an option in the future updates.

Comment: The built-in [Knife Project tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html#knife-project) might be better for this kind of thing..

Answer (score 2):

The work around would be to :

1. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
   to **Edit** go into mode
2. Hit  <kbd>N</kbd>  to open the navigation panel in the 3d viewport
3. Go to *"Mesh Display"* section
4. Turn on **Edge info** : *"Length*"

What I usually do is to quickly duplicate a vertex and extrude it to make
an edge. Move the vertex while holding on to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  will move your vertex while
using snap. Make sure your snap tool is set to snap to vertex, closest and also 
turn on snap to self. The edge would have the distance displayed between the 2 vertex with the above options turned on.

This way it makes the ruler tool quite obsolete for measuring straight / linear 
distances.